# How to exclude undocumented member functions/variables of a class from doxygen output?

Tags: c++, doxygen

As the title suggests, is this possible?

Basically, anything undocumented, to not appear in the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually export only the necessary, so: (no static and private as well)

```
# do not extract all
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
```

And also hide the uncommented stuff:

```
# hide undoc stuff
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = YES
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = YES
```

After you did this, only files in which you used the `@file` tag will be processed, and only the documented elements will be considered.

(doxygen 1.8.13)

Answer (score 0):

From [the FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html):

> Is your class / file / namespace documented? If not, it will not be extracted from the sources unless [EXTRACT_ALL](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all) is set to YES in the config file.

So, set it to NO.

Comment: I do have it set to NO, but I think it only works with globals functions/classes... not member functions.